# Why bond prices have increased or bond yields have decreased lately?

Tags: stocks, bonds

Why after covid bond prices have increased and consequently bond yields have decreased lately?

Answer (score 1):

Government bonds are (with some exceptions) considered to have no default risk, so their yields are determined purely by the expectation of the interest rates that they are based on. So if a vanilla fixed-rate government bond with no optionality goes down in yield, it means that the market thinks that interest rates will go *up* in the future from their current levels. As to why the market thinks that interest rates will go up, that's anybody's guess.

Corporate bonds are also dependent on the underlying interest rates, but they also change when the default risk of the guarantor company changes, so they can go down in yield (up in price) when the market thinks that there's a lower risk of default for the company.